# Can't see real device internal storage

Tags: java, android, storage, samsung-mobile

Hello android developers! I have question about android internal storage. I'm using real device to test app, but I have one problem, when I trying to choose file from internal storage, I'm using samsung galaxy s4,(API = 19), and here can't see internal storage, and for new Samsung which has (API>=23) shows internal storage in list below.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 intent.setType("*/*");
 startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CERT_REQUEST);
```

[storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWk4Y.png)

How to fix this one?

Answer (score 0):

To see files on your internal storage you must be rooted or have an application for that.